# Is scala.io.StdIn.readLine() a blocking call?

Tags: scala, blocking

Is scala.io.StdIn.readLine() a blocking call?

[From the docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/StdIn$.html), there is no mention of it being a blocking call.

I want to do something like this:

```
while(true){
    val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
    input match{
        case "quit" =>
            ...
        case "stats" =>
            ...
        case _ =>
            ...
    }
}
```

If it's not blocking, will it constantly loop, set input to null, and trigger **case _** each time?

If it is blocking, why isn't it shown in the docs? Or where can I see a definition that says it is blocking?

In general, how can I know whether or not a method is blocking?

Comment: Anything I/O related is blocking in any language. The question is what is being blocked, since there is not callback involved, we can assume that it blocks the calling thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I know whether or not a method is blocking?

Look at the return type of the method. If it is returning `Future`, `IO`, or some other [effectful](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/what-effects-effectful-mean-in-functional-programming) value `F[A]` that wraps a *pure* value `A` capable of modelling asynchronous computations, then assume it is non-blocking. For example consider

```
def f(v: Int): Future[Int] = Future(v + 1)
def g(v: Int): IO[Int] = IO(v + 1)
```

Here `f` and `g` are non-blocking in the sense of the thread that called them not being blocked until `v + 1` is evaluated. On the other hand, if the method is returning pure value like so

```
def h(v: Int): Int = v + 1
```

then it is best to assume it is blocking. Here `h` is blocking in the sense of the thread that called it being blocked until `v + 1` is computed.

Applying this principle to `readLine`

```
def readLine(): String
```

we see it is returning pure value `String` so we assume it is blocking. Analysing the source code we see the following stacktrace

```
java.io.Reader#read(char[], int, int)
java.io.BufferedReader#fill
java.io.BufferedReader#readLine(boolean)
java.io.BufferedReader#readLine()
scala.io.StdIn#readLine
```

where [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read-char:A-int-int-) states

> Reads characters into a portion of an array. This method will **block**
>   until some input is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the
>   stream is reached.

Comment: What does this mean "the end of the stream is reached." in this context? Since StdIn can never finish